# jQuery - Selecting inputs in closest/nearest DIV & add value to each input

Tags: jquery, html, forms, parent-child, closest

In my application, I use `$.get` and `yahoo APIs` to fetch *open gragh/og:* **title & description** from a giving **URL** by user.

*It works as snippet blow, or you can visit [jsfiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/rubioli/0qjq0bf7/2/)*

```js
$('#get-social-data-from-url').keyup(function(){
  var query = 'select * from html where url="' + $('input').val() + '" and xpath="*"';
  var url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

  $.get(url, function(data) {
    var html = $(data).find('html');
    $('#title').val(html.find("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content') || 'no title found');
    $('#description').val(html.find("meta[property='og:description']").attr('content') || 'no description found');
  });
});
```

```css
input{
  width:90%;
  height:50px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="main">
  <div class="one">
    <!-- Paste this link here:
    http://www.lifedaily.com/firefighters-help-pregnant-mom-who-lost-everything-in-a-fire/
    -->
    <input type="text" id="get-social-data-from-url" placeholder="Paste your link here">  
  </div>

  <div class="two">
    <lable>Title</lable>
    <input type="text" id="title" placeholder="title">
  
    <label>Description</label>
    <input type="text" id="description" placeholder="description">
  </div>
</div>
```

This function works fine when its only **one** `form`. My application is a dynamic application & in one page I have the same `form` many times *(as many as user want to add)*

So my `form` would look like this [jsfiddle snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/tukwu5xe/) & each of `input##get-social-data-from-url` will have **different** link and nothing will work/work correctly.

Now I am able to use `data-` to select correct `inputs` & that works fine, but for some reason, I can't get the `og:` **title** & **description** and I get *No title found*.

*This is how I do it now:*

```
$(function () {
    var fileFieldId;
    var query;
    var url;
    $(".get-social-data-from-url").keyup(function () {
        fileFieldId = $(this).attr('id');
        query = 'select * from html where url="' + $('input').val() + '" and xpath="*"';
        url = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

        $.get(url, function(data) {
          var html = $(data).find('html');
          $("input.post-title-create[data-title-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content') || 'no title found');

          $("textarea.post-description-create[data-description-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content') || 'no title found');

        });

    });
});
```

Only issue I have is that like previously, I can't get correct `og:` data.

Comment: dynamically created elements can have same class (usually so) but ***cannot*** have the same ids. If you cannot control that because you use some plugin, that plugin is designed/written wrong (seriously). For easily managing dynamically created elements, you can always use indices to prefix/suffix a base id to create different ids.

Comment: @KingKing Thanks for reply. Yeah thats correct I have different `IDs`, but I can't know the `ID`plugin applies to each `input`. But I can still give them a fixed `ID` as well. So to summarize, I have both fixed and different `ID` on each `input`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to fix the issue. First add `data-` to each `input` with same value, but different `data` name.

*for instance:*

```
<input class="post-title-create" data-title-id="attributes_1" type="text"  id="attributes_1493294690538_title">
```

*& `Javascript` code:*

```
$(function () {
    var fileFieldId;
    var fileFieldVal;
    var fileFieldClass;
    var query;
    var apiUrl;
    $(".get-social-data-from-url").keyup(function () {
        fileFieldId = $(this).attr('id');
        fileFieldClass = $(this).attr('class');
        fileFieldVal = $(this).val();
        query = 'select * from html where url="' + $(this).val() + '" and xpath="*"';
        apiUrl = 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + encodeURIComponent(query);

        $("h4[data-preview-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).text('updated');
        $("input.post-link-create[data-link-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).val(fileFieldVal);

        $.get(apiUrl, function(data) {
          var html = $(data).find('html');
          $("input.post-title-create[data-title-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:title']").attr('content') || 'no title found');
          $("textarea.post-description-create[data-description-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:description']").attr('content') || 'no title found');
          $("input.post-remote-image-create[data-remoteimg-id='" + fileFieldId + "']" ).val(html.find("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content') || 'no title found');
        });

    });
});
```